# Is it possible to give a string an empty value if it cant find the string

Tags: android, string

Is there away to create a blank string if it doesn't exist in the xml on the fly.

for example the following code:-

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String SManuf = bundle.getString("SManuf");
    String manuf = bundle.getString("manuf");
    String panel = bundle.getString("panel");
    setTitle("Instructions for "+manuf+" "+panel);


    String Ins = (SManuf + panel+"Noof");
    String InsI = (SManuf + panel);

   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Ins, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(Ins, "string", getPackageName());
    String InsNo = getResources().getString(resId);


    scrollviewTerms = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout linearlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    scrollviewTerms.addView(linearlayout);
   //for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    int foo = Integer.parseInt(InsNo);
    for (int i = 0; i < foo; i++)
    {

        LinearLayout linearManufTB = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearManufTB.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearlayout.addView(linearManufTB);
        Termsb = new Button(this);
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("PanMansTitle" + i, "string", getPackageName());
        String Terms = getResources().getString(id);
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Terms, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Termsb.setText(Terms);
        Termsb.setId(i);
        Termsb.setTextSize(30);
        Termsb.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        LinearLayout linearManufTV = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearManufTV.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearlayout.addView(linearManufTV);

        String TermsS = Terms.replaceAll("&","").replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll("/","").replaceAll(" / ","").replaceAll("/ ","").replaceAll(" /","".replaceAll("&amp;",""));

        TermstINS = new TextView(this);
        int ids = getResources().getIdentifier(InsI + TermsS, "string", getPackageName());

        String TermsTV = getResources().getString(ids);
        TermstINS.setText(TermsTV);
        TermstINS.setId(i);
        TermstINS.setTextSize(20);
        TermstINS.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
        TermstINS.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        LinearLayout linearManufTV2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearManufTV2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearlayout.addView(linearManufTV2);

        TermstNOTS = new TextView(this);
        int idn = getResources().getIdentifier(InsI + TermsS +"N", "string", getPackageName());

        String TermsTVN = getResources().getString(idn);

        TermstNOTS.setText(TermsTVN);
        TermstNOTS.setId(i);
        TermstNOTS.setTextSize(20);
        TermstNOTS.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#515151"));
        TermstNOTS.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        // b.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF,Typeface.ITALIC);



        Termsb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        TermstINS.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        TermstNOTS.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        linearManufTB.addView(Termsb);
        linearManufTV.addView(TermstINS);
        linearManufTV2.addView(TermstNOTS);

        if(TermstINS.length()== 0){ linearManufTB.setVisibility(View.GONE);linearManufTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);linearManufTV2.setVisibility(View.GONE);}else{
            linearManufTB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   linearManufTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);  linearManufTV2.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
```

this lists the titles and the instructions underneath, and notes below this.

however the list of Titles is fixed title0 to title 200+  but not all systems would have the same titles as they don't have the same features, but would share some of them.

rather than type out 200+ instructions and notes that are blank in the xml file, is it possible to say that the item isn't currently available,  generate a blank on the fly.

Thus making it behave smarter and not requiring lots of dead data to be entered.

At the moment anything that has no instructions wont show the header(which isn't empty), or instructions and notes but, that requires me to make a data entry for the xml file instructions and notes when there isn't any.

I am sure this is basic, but I cant find anything to cross reference. Any help of suitable examples or ideas on how to tackle it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getResources().getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)` returns `id` of the resource. If the resource doesn't exist it will return `0`.

You can change you code like this:

```
String defaultString = "";
String Terms = id != 0 ? getResources().getString(id) : defaultString;
```

Comment: Applied to all three points, ids and idn and working like a dream.

Answer (score 0):

```
String your_string = "";
```

This give an "empty" value to your string.